# Creating object in parameter passed as reference

Tags: c++

So this code won't work and it's probably a noob question.

```
const Foo foo(Bar(10));
```

where the constructor of Foo is:

```
Foo::Foo(Bar &bar) : bar(bar) {}
```

Error

> no matching function for call to Foo::Foo(Bar&)

Comment: This has been answered many, many times. Please search before asking.

Comment: I did search, nothing came up (perhaps due to lack in terms I knew to search with)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a reference to a const `Bar` object when saying

```
const Foo foo(Bar(10));
```

`Bar(10)` creates a temporary object.

You'll need to change your constructor signature:

```
Foo::Foo(const Bar &bar) : bar(bar) {}
      // ^^^^^
```

Comment: I'll be damned, that works. I feel stupid now. Thanks